# How to create a dropdown-menu that is wider than its title?

Tags: html, css

Here's the basic structure of my menu. I cannot change that.

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Bedroom</span></li>
    <li><span>Kitchen</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Pot</span></li>
            <li><span>Panholder</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Garden</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the layout I want to achieve:

```
Bedroom | Kitchen | Garden
        | Pot       |
        | Panholder |
```

As you can see *Panholder* is wider than kitchen. How can I disconnect the width of *Kitchen* from the width of it's sub-menu? (Sub-menus are allowed to overlap, I'm going to hide all submenus but the current one.

I'm looking for a non-javascript solution. If you want to try it out, [I've put it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYBA7/).

Comment: have you tried adding a css class for the ul li ul li containing a fixed width?

Comment: @Brandon: Just tried that. It works, *but* I cannot add any background-color this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: absolute` to your dropdown `<ul>`. In your jsFiddle, it would be the following:

```
body > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add `width: auto` to this place as well.

Answer (score 1):

Specifiy a larger width to the nested ul or li items such as:

```
ul { width: 100px; }
ul li ul { width: 200px; }
```

This should make the nested ul larger than it's parent.

In terms of the full dropdown CSS there are plenty of solutions available to you.  A good place to start would be [www.cssplay.co.uk](http://www.cssplay.co.uk)

Comment: Doesn't work for me because I don't know the widths of the menu items.